# Implicit rule in makefile

Tags: makefile, implicits

Consider the following makefile:

```
default: foo.o

clean:
    rm -f fmake test_second
%.o: %.c
    echo This is customized implicit rule

%.o: %.c
    echo This is overriden implicit rule
```

The output of the `make` command is

```
echo This is overriden implicit rule
This is overriden implicit rule
```

This is ok. However, if the makefile is instead:

```
default: foo.o

clean:
    rm -f fmake test_second
%.o: %.c
    echo This is customized implicit rule

%.o: %.z
    echo This is overriden implicit rule
```

then the output of the `make` command is

```
echo This is customized implicit rule
This is customized implicit rule
```

I expected that it would be the same as in the first example.
Why is it different? I have a both foo.c and foo.z files in a makefile's directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build an object file from all different kinds of source files: from C files, C++ files, FORTRAN files, etc.  In make, a rule only overrides if BOTH the target and the prerequisite patterns match.  Otherwise, it just defines a new way to build the target using a different prerequisite.